# Union two or more entities and merge into one list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to get a list from two different entities:

Entity1: Folder
Entity2: File

I would like to have a list of "Folders" and "Files".
If I understood it correctly a UNION will not work in JPA.

I can create two queries and merge them in one list:

```
List<Object> endResult = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> folderList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

endResult.addAll(folderList);
endResult.addAll(fileList);
```

This is currently working and I got a list, but it's not sorted
I got at first the Folder and afterwards the Files.

How can this be fixed?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort elements from two different classes, they need to implement a `Comparable` interface.

For example, you could create a new interface `Resource`:

```
    interface Resource extends Comparable<Resource> {

        String getPath();

        @Override
        default int compareTo(Resource o) {
            return getPath().compareTo( o.getPath() );
        }
    }

    class File implements Resource {
        ...
    }
    
    class Folder implements Resource {
        ...
    }
```

Then you can use `Collection#sort()`:

```
    List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
    resources.add( new File( "example.txt" ) );
    resources.add( new Folder( "examples/" ) );
    resources.sort(Resource::compareTo);
```

As an alternative, you could create an abstract super class and map the entities using [table per class inheritance](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-table-per-class):

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)   
abstract class Resource {
  
    String path;

    // Additional fields that they might have in common
}

@Entity
class File extends Resource {    
   ...
}

@Entity
class Folder extends Resource {        
   ...
}
```

Now you can run the following HQL query:

```
from Resource r order by r.path
```

and Hibernate ORM will generate a SQL query that does the union between the two tables.

Hibernate ORM also [allows querying interfaces](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-polymorphism), but I haven't tried it.